# React-native autocomplete giving regex trouble with special characters '()*?'

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-native

I'm writing an autocomplete input in React Native using react-native-autocomplete-input. Everything is working so far, except if I input a special regex character for my input, like '(', I get an error 'Invalid regular expression: missing ) or '*', the error is 'Invalid regular expression, nothing to repeat.

I'm trying to match country names and some countries have parenthesis, but also if a user types a ? or *, I don't want the app to crash.

Here is the function that searches through an object of countries with names:

```
  findCountry = (query) => {
    if (query === '') {
      return [];
    }
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
    return countries.filter(country => country.name.search(regex) >= 0);
  }
```

I think the error is somewhere in there. How do I set up the regex filter, so it ignores the special characters on input?

Here is the Autocomplete render function:

```
  render() {

    const { query } = this.state;
    const countries = this.findCountry(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();
    var { fetchingCountries, handleSearch } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteInput}
          data={countries.length === 1 && comp(query, countries[0].name) ? [] : countries}
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Search for a Country or Territory"
          renderItem={({ name }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: name })}>
              <Text style={styles.queryText}>
                {name}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.searchButton}
            onPress={() => handleSearch(query)}
          >
            {
              fetchingCountries
              ? <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="white" />
              : <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Search</Text>
            }
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ``new RegExp(`${query.trim().replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}`, 'i')``

Comment: Awesome, that worked. It just replaces what it thinks is regex with a string?

Comment: It escapes all those chars that are "special" and thus makes the regex engine match them as literal chars.